# IntelliJ support for renamed application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module Spring Boot application where I have more than one module containing an `applications.properties` file. I understand that I can only have one file with the name `application.properties` so I have renamed one of them and then explicitly include it via `@PropertySource("classpath:custom-name.properties")`. This works fine, but by doing this I lose the IntelliJ property file support for this file (autocomplete, jump to source, etc). The icon for the file changes as well and no longer has the spring symbol on it. How can I make IntelliJ support renamed `application.properties`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define custom name for Spring Boot configuration files by opening Spring facet in corresponding module(s), select Spring Boot autodetected fileset and then click "Customize Spring Boot" icon from toolbar. Then set textfield "spring.config.name" to "custom-name", all matching configuration files will be shown in tree below.

Comment: I actually do not have any auto detected configurarion in the facet for this module. I can manually add the `@Configuration` class inside this module and the the `custom-name.properties` as an additional properties source (which doesn't make it work like I want), but I do not have the customize option like I have for my modules that do have an autodetected entry in the facet.

Comment: So I was able to get it to autodetect this modules config in the project facets by replacing the `@Configuration` class in this module to `@SpringBootApplication` but I am afraid this might have unintended consequences. This module isn't meant to be it's own application and is only used as a dependency by other modules. Does it make sense to have this annotation on such modules?

Comment: It seems your usecase is covered in this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133335